# Get the node type based on text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML structure in which I want to find the tag type based on the text i.e. a tag containing a string like "Course Contents." I have the following HTML structure:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h3>
            Course Contents
        </h3>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here is my code:

```
HtmlNode ContentNode = CourseDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where((n => n.InnerText.Trim().ToLower() == "course contents")).FirstOrDefault();
```

So, how can I get the `h3` tag that contains the string?

and in addition I want to find the similar h3 tag below this HTML. Here is an example:

```
 <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <h3>
                Course Contents
            </h3>
        </td>
       <td>
         abc
       </td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <h3>
                Course Outline
            </h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

When I found the 1st h3 tag, then through code find the 2nd h3 tag, and retrieve the HTML in between these tags.

Comment: What do you mean by "the HTML in between these tags"? DO you want the `<td>abc</td>` or something else?

Comment: I mean that at first I found h3 tag, now if I get another h3 tag, then I want to retrieve the html in between these (h3) tags.
If the 2nd h3 tag is not found then retrieve all the html below the 1st h3 tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `InnerHtml` instead of `InnerText`, the node you select with your query will be the `<h3>` tag:

```
HtmlNode ContentNode = CourseDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where((n => n.InnerHtml.Trim().ToLower() == "course contents")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: yes that did the trick :-)
and how I can find the similar type of tag below this tag ?
like this is the h3 tag, and I want to find the similar h3 tag after this tag.

Comment: You need to update your question with a larger HTML sample so I can see what you mean more clearly.